# Why navigate to other windows in vimdiff?

Tags: git, vimdiff, mergetool

If I understand correctly, (when using `git mergetool` with `vimdiff` and `diff3` configured) only the MERGE version at the bottom is editable, in that saving changes here will result in a change to the working tree in the target branch.

The commands **CTRL+w+h, j, k, l** can be used in CLI to switch panes, but I don't see why you would want to navigate to say the LOCAL pane if the changes you save here have no effect. It's also confusing why when you save and exit the MERGE pane, it will then prompt you to save and exit the other 3 panes. Whatever your edits in LOCAL, BASE or REMOTE have no effect (right?)

Is it just for highlighting text to copy/paste to MERGE version for saving MERGE version?